# Traslation reset issue while upload on server

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I'm facing strange issue on server.

Using bitbucket & git for file & data management.

When data push to our development server 5-10 translations always reset to English.

We have 2 languages English as default & Chinese as another.

What will be cause of reset only those 5-10 tanslations?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue.

Comment: Always? Does your process involve running drush updates? In which language are you running those? Could be related to https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2910353